# NetworkManager not starting and dbus not working correctly after reboot - AlmaLinux9 (RHEL)

Tags: redhat, networkmanager, dbus

I have a Server with AlmaLinux9 installed which worked perfectly and i rebooted the server often and nothing happend. But recently i rebooted the server and now it get's no internet connection anymore. In the logs I saw, that NetworkManager failed to start. I managed to add manually an IP-Address to the network interface to work via SSH and not via VNC.

Also i noticed that booting and a shutdown takes longer.
Stays a minute at:

```
[3....] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
--- 1 minute between
[99...] Warning: Deprecated Driver is detected: ip6tables will not be maintained in a future major release and may be disabled
```

I haven't modified any special on the server
before the "one reboot". So i don't know exactly what's causing this issue. I tried restoring a backup where it was working but it doesn't help.

Output of /var/log/messages which seems interesting:

```
Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: Failed to start User Login Management.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: Stopped User Login Management.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: Starting User Login Management...
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3185]: ERROR listener_dispatch @ ../src/bus/listener.c +42: Bad file descriptor
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3185]:      dispatch_context_dispatch @ ../src/util/dispatch.c +344
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3185]:      broker_run @ ../src/broker/broker.c +225
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3185]:      run @ ../src/broker/main.c +261
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3185]:      main @ ../src/broker/main.c +295
Nov  2 13:22:59 host journal[3163]: Ready
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3163]: ERROR launcher_run @ ../src/launch/launcher.c +1445: Return code 1
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3163]:      run @ ../src/launch/main.c +152
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker[3185]: Dispatched 1 messages @ 2(±0)μs / message.
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: upower.service: Unexpected error response from GetNameOwner(): Connection terminated
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: rtkit-daemon.service: Unexpected error response from GetNameOwner(): Connection terminated
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: tuned.service: Unexpected error response from GetNameOwner(): Connection terminated
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: polkit.service: Unexpected error response from GetNameOwner(): Connection terminated
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unexpected error response from GetNameOwner(): Connection terminated
Nov  2 13:22:59 host systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unexpected error response from GetNameOwner(): Connection terminated
Nov  2 13:22:59 host dbus-broker-launch[3163]: Caught SIGCHLD of broker.
```

Also it seems the error occurs on bootup while firstly activating NetworkManager:

```
[root@host system-connections]# systemd-analyze
Bootup is not yet finished (org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.FinishTimestampMonotonic=0).
Please try again later.
Hint: Use 'systemctl list-jobs' to see active jobs
```

systemctl list-jobs displays following:

```
[root@host system-connections]# systemctl list-jobs
JOB   UNIT                                 TYPE  STATE  
144   multi-user.target                    start waiting
254   cloud-init.target                    start waiting
18323 NetworkManager.service               start running
289   systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting
18413 systemd-logind.service               start running
```

I tried to disable IPv6, reinstall dbus and NetworkManager, dnf update & upgrade but nothing seems to work and tried to google this issue but no one seems to have this same problem.

Hopefully anyone is able to help me. It would be such a pleasure.